# kotlin - how to to reference delegate when have same method name in override?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to analyze the [following sample code](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/textclassification-part-2/):

```
class StylingAndroidTextClassifier(
        private val context: Context,
        private val fallback: TextClassifier,
        private val factory: TextClassifierFactory = FrameworkFactory()
) : TextClassifier by fallback {

    private val stylingAndroid = "Styling Android"
    private val stylingAndroidUri = "https://blog.stylingandroid.com"
    private val regex = Regex("Styling\\s?Android", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)

    override fun suggestSelection(request: TextSelection.Request): TextSelection {
        return fallback.suggestSelection(request)

    }

    override fun classifyText(request: TextClassification.Request): TextClassification {
        return fallback.classifyText(request)
    }
}
```

**my question has to do with why fallback has to be referenced at all. The class should now include the fallbacks methods but in this specific case the method names will clash. in such a case is this why we use fallback.suggestSelection() instead of just suggestionSelection()** ? i want to know why the author has to delegate to fallback ?

instead i was thinking this would work:

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun suggestSelection(request: TextSelection.Request): TextSelection {
        return suggestSelection(request)
       // return fallback.suggestSelection(request)
    }
```

notice how i remove the fallback. will this be an infinite loop or will it call into the fallback's implementatino of "suggestSelection ?

Comment: Normally in any language such delegate reference is resolved using explicit object of the containing class, instead of this pointer for the current class

Comment: But the ide shows the delegates methods also. Try delegating to a class that is different then the host class. Then you'll see additional methods added to the preview quick pick method hints

Comment: if i always should reference the delegate object, then what is the use for "by fallback" syntax ?  isn't it suppose to make me be able to call it without referencing it ?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve, will led to recursive call and recursion is valid programming mechanism, that's why its important to qualify. In-fact recursion needs an exit point and in this case it will lead to infinite looping and stack overflow or similar exception

Comment: i think i get it. if the delegate has the same type as the containing class then we should reference it explicitly.

Comment: Explicit qualifier when there's ambiguity is a valid mechanism, otherwise how do expect the resolution at compile / run-time.

Comment: not just type, any thing common which can cause ambiguity and its valid to call anyone, then it needs to be resolved and programmer shall specify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Crux of the question is, why do we need the following call:

```
 override fun suggestSelection(request: TextSelection.Request): TextSelection {
        return fallback.suggestSelection(request)}
```

> when `private val fallback: TextClassifier` is explicitly included, then why and explicit qualifier.

Main reason is if we write a code like this, then depending upon the programming language, one of the two things can happen.

```
 override fun suggestSelection(request: TextSelection.Request): TextSelection {
        return suggestSelection(request)}
```

1. A Recursive call, which has no break point in this case, thus infinite
2. An ambiguous call, where Compiler doesn't know, which `suggestSelection` it refers to, in either case it is better to explicitly qualify with object name like `fallback`, so that it is clear at run-time, **which method needs to be called**